# Export tables from specific user in connection in sql developer

Tags: database, oracle, export, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to export all tables from specific user in oracle sql developer.

For example:

Connection: allusers (remote)
  User/schema: user1
    Tables: table1
            table2
            tablen

I need to export all the tables and relationships from user1, generating an .sql or .ddl file.

After this, I'm gonna import the file in my local data base.

Connection: local
   user/schema: user1(imported from the file)
     tables: (all tables from the exported file)

How can I do that?

I was trying with data base copy, but my remote connection has not granted privileges to get data from an external user, and I can't grant privileges because I'm not the remote data base administrator.

Any idea?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Look at the impdp and expdp

Comment: Login as the schema owner, then use the tools, export feature. If a large schema, consider data pump or littlefoots suggestion below, but you'll need an Oracle client to run exp utility

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer *oldfashioned* export/import approach. Why? Because those utilities are designed for such things, moving *things* around.

For this simple example, I'm connected to a remote database (ORCL) which is 11gR2. As I'm exporting Scott's schema which doesn't contain anything special, I'm using the *original* EXP utility instead of Data Pump. It is simpler and creates the DMP file locally.

```
c:\Temp>exp scott/tiger@orcl file=scott_remote.dmp

Export: Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on ╚et Pro 27 21:01:50 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.


Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Real Application Clusters, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP,
Data Mining and Real Application Tes
Export done in EE8MSWIN1250 character set and AL16UTF16 NCHAR character set
. exporting pre-schema procedural objects and actions
. exporting foreign function library names for user SCOTT
. exporting PUBLIC type synonyms
. exporting private type synonyms
. exporting object type definitions for user SCOTT
About to export SCOTT's objects ...
. exporting database links
. exporting sequence numbers
. exporting cluster definitions
. about to export SCOTT's tables via Conventional Path ...
. . exporting table                          BONUS          0 rows exported
. . exporting table                           DEPT          4 rows exported
. . exporting table                            EMP         14 rows exported
. . exporting table                      EMPLOYEES          1 rows exported
. . exporting table                       SALGRADE          5 rows exported
. . exporting table                           TEST          1 rows exported
. exporting synonyms
. exporting views
. exporting stored procedures
. exporting operators
. exporting referential integrity constraints
. exporting triggers
. exporting indextypes
. exporting bitmap, functional and extensible indexes
. exporting posttables actions
. exporting materialized views
. exporting snapshot logs
. exporting job queues
. exporting refresh groups and children
. exporting dimensions
. exporting post-schema procedural objects and actions
. exporting statistics
Export terminated successfully without warnings.

c:\Temp>
```

Target database is 11gXE on my laptop. IMP utility is used to *import* data. I'll use SYSTEM XE user to import into a different schema (MIKE) - note `FROMUSER` & `TOUSER` parameters.

```
c:\Temp>imp system/pwd@xe file=scott_remote.dmp fromuser=scott touser=mike

Import: Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on ╚et Pro 27 21:14:58 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.


Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

Export file created by EXPORT:V11.02.00 via conventional path

Warning: the objects were exported by SCOTT, not by you

import done in EE8MSWIN1250 character set and AL16UTF16 NCHAR character set
import server uses AL32UTF8 character set (possible charset conversion)
. importing SCOTT's objects into MIKE
. . importing table                        "BONUS"          0 rows imported
. . importing table                         "DEPT"          4 rows imported
. . importing table                          "EMP"         14 rows imported
. . importing table                    "EMPLOYEES"          1 rows imported
. . importing table                     "SALGRADE"          5 rows imported
. . importing table                         "TEST"          1 rows imported
About to enable constraints...
Import terminated successfully without warnings.

c:\Temp>
```

Piece of cake, takes no time whatsoever. Try it.